# Explicit expression for $p$-norm distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Assume a random variable $X$ with the distribution $x$ ~ $a(\sigma,p) \exp\left(-\frac{|x|^p}{\sigma}\right)$.

For a given $p$ and $\sigma$, we have $$a(\sigma,p) = 1/\int \exp\left(-\frac{|x|^p}{\sigma}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ And for $p=2$, we get a Gaussian distribution; for $p=1$ we get a Laplace distribution. There are explicit expressions of $a(\sigma)$ for these cases. My question is if $1<p<2$ or even $0<p<1$, do we have the explicit expression for $a(\sigma,p)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we use the substitution $u = |x|^p / \sigma$, we get:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp \left(-\frac{|x|^p}{\sigma} \right) dx = \tfrac 2 p \sigma^{\frac 1 p} \int_{0}^\infty u^{\frac 1 p - 1} e^{-u} du = \tfrac 2 p \sigma^{\frac 1 p} \Gamma\left( \tfrac 1 p \right),$$
where $\Gamma$ denotes the  [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Note that $\Gamma(1) = 1$ and $\Gamma(\frac 1 2) = \sqrt{\pi}$ so this reduces to $2\sigma$ when $p = 1$, and $\sqrt{\pi \sigma}$ when $p = 2$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function) for a list of  particular values of the gamma function.

Comment: Yes, there is. Thanks.

Comment: The value of this gamma function has to be computed numerically right?

Comment: Yes. But its value is known at many special points - I've included a wikipedia link in my answer.